# 12.04 boots to black screen

Tags: 12.04, boot-failure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I have downloaded the last release of Ubuntu 12.04 and when I wanted to install it from the Live CD it freeze and display a black screen after choosing install  so I tried the boot option **"acpi=off"** then the Live CD boot and I installed the Ubuntu successfully, after the restart Ubuntu can't boot and the same problem appeared even when editing the boot options **"acpi=off"**, So now I do not know how to solve this problem and what cause it.